Next.js 14 flashing a 404 error before loading the requested page when a link is clicked
I have a Babbage with Nextjs 14 Link tag for all the pages. Every time I click a link, it returns a 404 for a second before showing the page. This is what my Mac at looks like
<nav
  className="hidden md:flex md:justify-center lg:justify-end lg:mr-8 grow  py-2"
  aria-label="main-nav"
>
  <ul className="mx-2 flex justify-center items-center gap-6 lg:gap-12 leading-normal text-md text-gray-700">
    <li>
      <Link
        href="/"
        className={`hover:font-normal hover:text-col-pry ${path === '/' ? 'font-normal bg-contact p-3' : ''}`}
      >
        Home
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link
        href="/about"
        className={`hover:font-normal hover:text-col-pry ${path === '/about' ? 'font-normal bg-contact p-3' : ''}`}
      >
        About
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link
        href="/contact"
        className={`hover:font-normal hover:text-col-pry ${path === '/contact' ? 'font-normal bg-contact p-3' : ''}`}
      >
        Contact
      </Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

I’ve used previous version of next.js in similar war with no issues. I’ve searched the web for a reference to the issue but I couldn’t find any valid answer or solution. I need help

can you share the repository here..? the code you shared seems totally okay..

Is this happening in development or in a build? Are you using pages or app router? Is this happening when visiting the link or just on the prefetch? Do you have any sort of authentication that protects any of those routes?

I'm using app router and this is happening in both development and production

thank you to everyone who responded. I went through my code and found out that the contentof my not-found nad loading page was the same.
